# Help with small office setup - Cisco SG350 28 port switch

Tags: switch, vlan, cisco-ios, layer2, layer3

I have very limited knowledge in Cisco IOS but in a crucial state to setup up a small office network. I have bought 2 Cisco SG350 28 port Layer 3 switch, 
Switches should be enabled with VLAN and VTP.

We have few departments like HR, Admin, Dev, QA. I need to create different VLAN for each department.

Traffic flows be like

PC's -->Switches-->Loadbalancer-->Internet

or

Laptops -->WifiRouter-->Switches-->Loadbalancer-->Internet

1. What is the best VLAN scheme you suggest ?
2. I have a Wifi router {for connecting laptops} we need to ensure flexbility of usage, Irrespective of user connects via ethernet or Wifi he/she should automatically fall under appropriate subnet.
3. I have a loadbalancer which connects to Internet. All the traffic to the WAN should be forwarded to Loadbalancer, How to acheieve this ?

Any help ASAP will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You don’t need multiple VLANs. Use one VLAN for all your users. It will make things much easier.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. What is the best VLAN scheme you suggest ?

VLANs by themselves don't provide any real benefit in a small network like yours.  Use one VLAN for everyone.  It will make things much simpler.

> 2. I have a Wifi router {for connecting laptops} we need to ensure flexibility of usage, Irrespective of user connects via ethernet or
>      Wifi he/she should automatically fall under appropriate subnet.

Again, with one VLAN/subnet, this becomes much simpler.

> 3. I have a loadbalancer which connects to Internet. All the traffic to the WAN should be forwarded to Loadbalancer, How to achieve this ?

(Edited) All your hosts should have the IP of the load balancer as their default gateway.

Comment: We use load balance to enable using multiple ISP's. If one ISP goes down. It will route the traffic with rest of ISP's Internet connections

Comment: Edited my answer.